# Ten minutes to twelve

Tags: usage

We usually say

> Cook it for 10 to 12 minutes

But is the following correct?

> Cook it for 10 minutes to 12

Comment: It's correct but it has a different meaning.  "10 minutes to 12" means "11:50".  It's clock time.

Comment: It's not very idiomatic to interrupt the "range" element like that in your specific context. So the best "rule of thumb" is probably to avoid it, but note that there are exceptions. For example, *It might cost anything from 5 dollars to 50* is just as natural as *...anything from 5 to 50 dollars.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "10 minutes **to** twelve" you are saying 10 minutes **before** twelve.

When you say "10 **to** 12 minutes" you are using the word **to** as a range. Many words in the English language have several different meanings, which are dependant on context.

Comment: To go one step further, _"Cook it for 10 minutes to 12"_ makes no sense, but _"Cook it **at** 10 minutes to 12"_ would mean start cooking at 11:50.